# Accessing Application.Current.Properties from native Android Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Forms app and I am adding an AppWidget to the native Android Xamarin project to give users a widget which they can pin on their home screen and use to interact. The Xamarin Forms app stores state in

```
 Application.Current.Properties["MyId"]
```

How can I access this from the native Android Xamarin code, since `Application` is in the `Xamarin.Forms` namespace?

Comment: N.B. I have posted this on the Xamarin forums [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/140939/accessing-application-current-properties-from-native-android-xamarin/) too

Comment: Have you try this `var myId = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["Id"];`

Comment: Doh, I don't know whether to feel delighted or feel like an idiot: that works. Thanks @Arvindraja, feel free to write up your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access `Application.Properties` from projects native like *Android* or *iOS*. Please use the simple code snippet

```
var myId = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["Id"];
```